# EURIBOR dependent product pricing

Tags: libor, short-rate, modelling

3M Euribor rates still exists (see https://www.ice.com/) and there still exist structured products depending on them : for instance a CMS spread whose udnerlying CMS rates depend on it. But also range accruals, TARNs etc.

My question is simple : which simple model to use today to price such products ?

I tried to think a bit :

1. all discounts are done using ESTR so the model will have to diffuse the ESTR rate, probably in a short rate model way
2. the model will have to either A) diffuse the forward 3M Euribor rates B) diffuse a short rate associated to theoretical zero-coupons (not discount zero-coupons) allowing to calculate the forward rates
3. As 2.A is too much complicated for me I stick to 2.B : there should be correlations between the factors from the diffusion in 1 and the factors of the diffusion in 2.B : this is also to complicated : can I supposed a deterministic spread ?

Consider something like the following "model" :

$$r^{\textrm{ESTR}}_t = f_{0,t} + x_t$$

where $x_t$ is diffused such that $r^{\textrm{ESTR}}_t$ is a 2 or 3 factors Hull-White model and such that the discount zero-coupons are $P^{\textrm{disc}}_{0,T} = e^{-\int_0^T r^{\textrm{ESTR}}_s ds}$, and

$$r^{\textrm{EURIBOR}}_t = s(t) + r^{\textrm{ESTR}}_t$$

where $s(t)$ is a deterministic function, such that if one defines theoretical forward zero-coupon $P^{\textrm{fwd}}_{t,T} := e^{-\int_t^T r^{\textrm{EURIBOR}}_s ds}$ then the EURIBOR forward rates are $\frac{P^{\textrm{fwd}}_{t,T} - P^{\textrm{fwd}}_{t,T+3M}}{\delta P^{\textrm{fwd}}_{t,T}}$.

Would that be a reasonable model to price such products ? If not, what would some "similar" but reasonable ?